# LINUX opencv hough transform circle

Tags: opencv, geometry, hough-transform

I am using code from [the page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html). It works on most of my images. But it is failing on the attached image - the code fails to recognize outer dial/boundary of the gauge (in my original image, there is not inner white circle) [image]

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that the problen is related to Linux?

Comment: i am not saying that it is a linux problem. I just wanted to provide the OS info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are after...

[image]

if so it's a question of tweaking a few parameters. In particular, the min and max circle radius and the circle_distance (min distance between detected circles).

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/foundry/a7b0e95c52f6ace97315).

**update**
if you want to relate the minimum radius to the image dimensions, you could do something like this:

```
float minRadius = MIN(img.size().width, img.size().height) * 0.5;
```

and feed that to the houghCircles function.

The params I actually used (as per the gist):

```
 HoughCircles(     img
                 , circles
                 , CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT //method – Detection method to use. 
                 // Currently,  the only implemented method is 
                 // CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT , which is  basically 21HT , 
                 // described in [Yuen90].
                 , 1 //p – Inverse ratio of the accumulator resolution to the 
                 // image resolution. For example, if dp=1 , the accumulator has 
                 // the same resolution as the input image. If dp=2 , 
                 // the accumulator has half as big width and height.
                 , 60  //minDist – Minimum distance between the centers of the 
                 // detected circles. If the parameter is too small, multiple 
                 // neighbor circles may be falsely detected in addition to a 
                 // true one. If it is too large, some circles may be missed.
                 , 100 //cannyThreshold – The higher threshold of the two 
                 // passed  to the gpu::Canny() edge detector 
                 // (the lower one is twice smaller).
                 , 30 //votesThreshold – The accumulator threshold for the circle 
                 // centers at the detection stage. The smaller it is, the more 
                 // false circles may be detected.
                 , 250 //minRadius – Minimum circle radius.
                 , 300 //maxRadius – Maximum circle radius.
                 );
```

Comments are lifted from the [openCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#void%20HoughCircles%28InputArray%20image,%20OutputArray%20circles,%20int%20method,%20double%20dp,%20double%20minDist,%20double%20param1,%20double%20param2,%20int%20minRadius,%20int%20maxRadius%29).

Comment: Thanks for providing details of the function. How can i say that minRadius should be the minimum(image width, image height)*0.5?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide values that you used in below call : `HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );`

Comment: I looked at your updated answer and it helps. But still i am not getting the red circle that you have shown in your image. Would it be possible to share what values do you use for different parameters - especially the min and max circle radius and the circle_distance that allowed you to get that circle?

Comment: @user2543622 - it _should_ be the same as i have put int the answer (minRadius 250, maxRadius 300, minDist 60) - if you are unable to repeat that result i will double-check my code.

Comment: i tweaked those parameters and was able to get the circle ..thanks

Comment: would it be possible to look at my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778513/linux-opencv-hough-transform-circle-and-cropping-image

Comment: @user2543622 - thanks for the invite: looks as if you have a couple of useful answers already! If you need more help I would take those answers and experiment with them, see how far you get then post another question with more detail if you get stuck - i'll be happy to help out if I can.