# How to crop circles (found with Hough Transform) in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, crop, geometry

I'm using the code from the [page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html). It works very well and I get a circle that I am looking for. All my image have only 1 circle and I have modified parameters of `HoughCircles()` such that the code returns only 1 circle.

How can I crop my original image so that the new image has only the circle (and area within it) and save the new image as a JPEG or PNG file?

Based upon original code, the center of the circle is given by

```
(cvRound(circles[1][0]), cvRound(circles[1][1]));
```

and the radius is given by

```
cvRound(circles[1][2]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [copyTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#mat-copyto) with a mask to retrieve the part of image inside the circle, and then you can crop according to the bounding box of the circle.

You save images with [imwrite](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite).

This small example should get you started.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Your initial image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Your Hough circle
    Vec3f circ(100,50,30); // Some dummy values for now

    // Draw the mask: white circle on black background
    Mat1b mask(img.size(), uchar(0));
    circle(mask, Point(circ[0], circ[1]), circ[2], Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

    // Compute the bounding box
    Rect bbox(circ[0] - circ[2], circ[1] - circ[2], 2 * circ[2], 2 * circ[2]);

    // Create a black image
    Mat3b res(img.size(), Vec3b(0,0,0));

    // Copy only the image under the white circle to black image
    img.copyTo(res, mask);

    // Crop according to the roi
    res = res(bbox);

    // Save the image
    imwrite("filename.png", res);

    // Show your result
    imshow("Result", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
HoughCircles(src, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, parameter_1, parameter_2, parameter_3, parameter_4, parameter_5);

for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    circleroi = src(Rect(center.x - radius, coordinate
                    center.y - radius, 
                    radius *2,         
                    radius * 2));       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a Region of Interest (ROI) on your image based on the coordinates of the circle, then `imwrite` will only save the cropped portion:

```
cv::Rect roi(x, y, w, h); // I let you do the math ;)
cv::Mat cropped = original(roi);
cv::imwrite("cropped.png", cropped);
```

Comment: would first line return a circle? it seems to a rectangular area :(

Comment: Well… images are rectangular. You cannot have a round image. If you want you can color pixels outside of your circle in black, or even better use an alpha channel to make them transparent.

Comment: nice idea, that will work to. Please provide suggestions to do that.

Comment: In a loop over rows and columns, compute the distance from the pixel to the center of the circle. If it is greater than the radius, color it black (or set its alpha value to zero). Note that you can do that on the cropped image directly (less pixels to iterate over).

Comment: would it be possible to provide at least some sample code or a reference example? I am new to c++ and need some help

Comment: It's a great learning exercise! Why don't you try first, using my hints and a little bit of trial and error, and if you are really stuck you can always ask a question on SO!

Answer (score 1):

To crop circle after circles=HoughCircles(...)

```
if len(circles) == 1:
    x, y, r = circles[0][0]
    print x, y, r
    mask = np.zeros((w0,h0),dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.circle(mask,(x,y),r,(255,255,255),-1,8,0)
    #cv2.imwrite(argv[2],mask)
    out = img*mask
    white = 255-mask
    cv2.imwrite(argv[2],out+white)
```

Comment: where did you get w0 and h0?

Comment: `w0` and `h0` is width/height of `img` (or `mask`), i.e. -- `w0 = img.shape[0]`, `h0 = img.shape[1]`.