# How do I extract the circle in new image after use the OpenCV function HoughCircles to detect circles in an image in JaVa?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I want to extract the circle in the image in new matrix , How can I do that after do HoughCircles using JaVa/OpenCv

Note that the image contains only one circle.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31781561/5008845). Again, its C++, but you can convert easily to Java.

Comment: Also, add the code you tried in your question, along with a sample image, so that other can copy&paste your code and run it on your image.